# How does the "Or" operator work? (In C++)

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int x = 0;

int main(){
std::cin >> x;
if (x == 5 || 6) {
std::cout << "5 or 6\n";
}
else {
std::cout << "Not 5 or 6\n";
}
    return 0; 
}
```

This simple code only returns "5 or 6" to the console, no matter what number you put in it.  I really don't understand why. If || is the or operator, then it should work. If x is 5 or 6 it should display "5 or 6". If it's not, display "Not 5 or 6". Could someone please explain?

Comment: `x == 5 || 6` means if *either* `x == 5` is true *or* `6` is true, and the latter always is. To test whether `x` is `5` or `6` use `x == 5 || x == 6`.

Comment: And `6` is true, because it's nonzero.

Comment: What you probably mean to do is `(x == 5 || x == 6) `

Answer (score 5):

```
if (x == 5 || 6)
```

should be

```
if (x == 5 || x == 6)
```

You think you're checking "if x is 5 or x is 6", but you're actually checking "if x is 5, or if 6". In C++, any non-zero number by itself in an if-statement evaluates to true, so your initial `if` is equivalent to:

```
if (x == 5 || true)
```

The behaviour is specified in the C++ standard as follows:

> A zero value, null
>     pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false; any
>     other value is converted to true.